Archivo HTML no carga después de incluir script
Este es mi archivo htm:
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Result List</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sendToInfolexForm">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelHead1"></ml>
        </legend>
        <div class="radio allResultList">
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="SelectAllDocumentsFromResultList"
            name="part"
            value="3"
            onclick="jQuery('[class=selection]').hide();"
            checked="checked" />
          <span>
            <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelAllDocuments">
              All result list
            </ml>
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="radio resultListDocumentSelection">
          <input
            id="partSelectionRadio"
            type="radio"
            name="part"
            value="4"
            onclick="jQuery('[class=selection]').show();" />
          <span>
            <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelSelectedDocuments">
              List results selection documents
            </ml>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="selection" style="display: none">
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="partSelection" name="partSelection" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>
              <ml
                node="sendToInfolexDocument"
                key="htmlLabelSelectedDocumentsText">
                Write document numbres
              </ml>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Results" style="display: none">
          <input type="text" id="NumResults" name="NumResults" />
        </div>

        <!-- Selección de acción -->
        <legend>Seleccione una opción</legend>
        <div class="radio-row">
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="SendToInfolexSaveLinkRadioButton"
              name="option"
              value="SaveLink"
              checked="checked" />
            <label for="SendToInfolexSaveLinkRadioButton">Guardar enlace</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="SendToInfolexDownLoadDocumentRadioButton"
              name="option"
              value="downloaddocument" />
            <label for="SendToInfolexDownLoadDocumentRadioButton"
              >Descargar documento</label
            >
            <select id="downloaddocumentdropdown">
              <option value="DownloadDocx">DOCX</option>
              <option value="DownloadPdf">PDF</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="SendToInfolexDownTemplateDocumentRadioButton"
              name="option"
              value="downloadtemplate" />
            <label for="SendToInfolexDownTemplateDocumentRadioButton"
              >Descargar plantilla</label
            >
            <select id="downloadtemplatedropdown">
              <option value="DownloadDotx">DOTX</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name="option"]').change(function () {
          if ($('input[name="option"]:checked').val() === "SaveLink") {
            $('input[name="part"][value="3"]').val("1");
            $('input[name="part"][value="4"]').val("2");
          }
        });

        if ($('input[name="option"]:checked').val() === "SaveLink") {
          $('input[name="part"][value="3"]').val("1");
          $('input[name="part"][value="4"]').val("2");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Este archivo htm se carga como parte del contenido dentro de una ventana emergente en mi aplicación. Cuando no tenía ningún script, se cargaba perfectamente.
Como necesitaba agregar algo de lógica, añadí este script simple, pero cuando fui a probarlo, el contenido ya no se carga. Tampoco recibo ningún error en la consola.
Estoy usando la versión 1.8.3 de jQuery, ya que es la versión utilizada en la mayoría de los productos de mi empresa.
Intenté usar algunas versiones más recientes, pero los resultados fueron los mismos. También intenté incluir el script dentro del head, en caso de que algo tuviera que ejecutarse antes de que el contenido se cargara completamente, pero nuevamente, ese no era el problema.
El código que inyecta el html en la ventana emergente es básicamente este:
public JavaScriptObject GetSendToInfolexPopup(JavaScriptObject request)
{
    var response = new JavaScriptObject();

    try
    {
        SendToInfolexController.LoadSendToInfolexPopupResponse(response);

        // This has the content of the html
        var html = DocumentView.Instance.GenerateHtmlPopup(ShortListController.Instance.GetSendToInfolexPopupModel());

        response["html"] = new JavaScriptString(html);

        response.Add("code", new JavaScriptNumber((int)ReturnExportCode.Ok));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.error(new ObjLog("There were some errors in the operation", ex));

        response.Add("error", new JavaScriptString(SendToInfolexLanguage.Instance.RecoverHtmlSendToInfolexError()));
        response.Add("code", new JavaScriptNumber((int)ReturnExportCode.Error));
    }

    return response;
}

Después de depurar, confirmé que el valor de la variable "html" es el mismo que el contenido en el html. La función de callback en el archivo js que invoca este código contiene el diálogo que aparece con el contenido html:
sendableToInfolex.dialog = jQuery(response.value.html).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  closeText: getLanguageText("alertMessage", "closeButton"),
  width: 470,
  height: "auto",
  modal: true,
  title: response.value.title,
  show: "scale",
  hide: "scale",
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function () {
    jQuery(sendableToInfolex).trigger("open");
  },
  close: function () {
    sendableToInfolex.Close();
    jQuery(this).remove();
  },
  create: function (event, ui) {
    centerDialogInIEandEdge(this);
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      text: response.value.buttonCancel,
      click: function () {
        jQuery(this).dialog("close");
      },
    },

    {
      text: response.value.buttonOk,
      click: function () {
        if (
          window.autohideDialog &&
          document.getElementById("popup_container_alert")
        )
          return;
        sendableToInfolex.SendToInfolex();
      },
    },
  ],
});

Todo esto funcionaba perfectamente antes de incluir el script.
Añado un pequeño snippet para que se vea que el código funciona si lo tengo aislado. Como he dicho anteriormente, en mi variable "html" puedo ver haciendo uso del debugger de Visual Studio exactamente lo mismo que se ve si se ejecuta este trozo de código. Sin embargo, en el pop up de mi aplicación web, no se ve nada y no aparece en el DOM.


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="option"]').change(function () {
        if ($('input[name="option"]:checked').val() === 'SaveLink') {
            $('input[name="part"][value="3"]').val('1');
            $('input[name="part"][value="4"]').val('2');
            console.log("part value 1 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="1"]').val());
            console.log("part value 2 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="2"]').val());
            }
        else {
            $('input[name="part"][value="1"]').val('3');
            $('input[name="part"][value="2"]').val('4');
            console.log("part value 3 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="3"]').val());
            console.log("part value 4 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="4"]').val());
        }
        });

    if ($('input[name="option"]:checked').val() === 'SaveLink') {
        $('input[name="part"][value="3"]').val('1');
        $('input[name="part"][value="4"]').val('2');
        console.log("part value 1 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="1"]').val());
        console.log("part value 2 is: " + $('input[name="part"][value="2"]').val());
    }
});
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result List</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sendToInfolexForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelHead1"></ml>
            </legend>
            <div class="radio allResultList">
                <input type="radio" id="SelectAllDocumentsFromResultList" name="part" value="3" onclick="jQuery('[class=selection]').hide();" checked="checked" />
                <span>
                    <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelAllDocuments">All result list</ml>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="radio resultListDocumentSelection">
                <input id="partSelectionRadio" type="radio" name="part" value="4" onclick="jQuery('[class=selection]').show();" />
                <span>
                    <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelSelectedDocuments">List results selection documents</ml>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="selection" style="display: none">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="partSelection" name="partSelection" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <ml node="sendToInfolexDocument" key="htmlLabelSelectedDocumentsText">Write document numbres</ml>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Results" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" id="NumResults" name="NumResults" />
            </div>

            <!-- Selección de acción -->
            <legend>Seleccione una opción</legend>
            <div class="radio-row">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="SendToInfolexSaveLinkRadioButton" name="option" value="SaveLink" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="SendToInfolexSaveLinkRadioButton">Guardar enlace</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="SendToInfolexDownLoadDocumentRadioButton" name="option" value="downloaddocument" />
                    <label for="SendToInfolexDownLoadDocumentRadioButton">Descargar documento</label>
                    <select id="downloaddocumentdropdown">
                        <option value="DownloadDocx">DOCX</option>
                        <option value="DownloadPdf">PDF</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" id="SendToInfolexDownTemplateDocumentRadioButton" name="option" value="downloadtemplate" />
                    <label for="SendToInfolexDownTemplateDocumentRadioButton">Descargar plantilla</label>
                    <select id="downloadtemplatedropdown">
                        <option value="DownloadDotx">DOTX</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




No se de jQuery pero al editar tu pregunta me di cuenta de que en el script te repites y el segundo if se encuentra fuera del change. No se si tenga algo que ver, porque no hace sentido repetirlo, pero si necesitas hacerlo podrías crear una función y solamente llamarla en ambos casos.

@René Dependiendo de lo que haya hecho el usuario actualmente, puede que nada más abrir el pop up, esté seleccionada la segunda opción. Quiero ejecutar ese código si se da este caso y, también, si el pop up carga con otra de las 2 opciones y el usuario selecciona esta opción (por eso el .change). Se que repito el código pero no quiero crear un archivo js que sólo contenga esto.

¿Intentaste cargar el script (la biblioteca) antes de cerrar el body? Meramente para probar.

@padaleiana Si. El script lo tenía originalmente al final del body, dentro de las etiquetas
